# Force close using Admob

Tags: android, admob

I've just updated my android with sdk-r17 and eclipse with ADT-17. Now all my applications that use admob caused force close after building and running it either on real device or emulator (It worked well before updating)

Here is my xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/admob"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxx"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_agent"
    android:layout_above="@id/admob"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/l_slide_right"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/bg_list_selector"
    android:divider="#3f3f3f"
```

The logcat error message is:

```
AndroidRuntime(29533): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.londatiga.xxx/net.londatiga.xxx.xxx}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
```

Any solutions?

Comment: I've reproduced this as well.  We're investigating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is a dependency jars in Android projects. The solution seems to see http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Comment: Thanx for the solution, it works well now. This problem arised because libraries are not managed the same way with the new ADT17.